# cannot not step into function while debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

my simple test cpp is followed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void hello(string str) {
    cout << str << endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    string str = "hello world!";
    hello(str);
    return 0;
}
```

and I compile the cpp with command:

```
g++ hello.cpp -o hello -g
```

and then run as debug mode:

```
cgdb hello
(gdb) b main
(gdb) r
(gdb) n
(gdb) s
```

after I use step command in gdb, I got the following errors:

```
std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string (this=0x7fffffffe5c0, __str="hello world!") at /build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h:399
399     /build/gcc/src/gcc-build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/include/bits/basic_string.h: No such file or directory.
```

I found that this error only happen when the function has arguments with type of string. For example:

```
void hello(int i);
```

I can step into the function hello without any problem.

I use the following command to find where allocator.h is:

```
sudo find / | grep allocator.h
```

and I got the results as follow(only list part of the results):

```
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ext/bitmap_allocator.h
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ext/debug_allocator.h
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ext/new_allocator.h
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ext/extptr_allocator.h
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ext/throw_allocator.h
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ext/pool_allocator.h
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ext/array_allocator.h
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/ext/malloc_allocator.h
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bits/c++allocator.h
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/allocator.h
/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/bits/uses_allocator.h
/usr/include/gc/gc_allocator.h
```

Why would this happen?
THX!!!

Comment: stdio.h is a C header. Remove that include and try again

Comment: @bejado not related to current problem.

Comment: It might not be related, but it certainly is fishy

Comment: It's possible that you didn't  compile libstdc++ with DEBUG_FLAGS = ON or you do not have access to the folder. /build/gcc/src/gcc-build/ is branch for sources as they were last time for compilation, /usr/include/ contains only headers for user

Comment: @bejado nothing fobids to use them, "allowed" by standard <cstdio> would cnormally contail only one line that includes stdio.h

Comment: I have no clue what you're trying to say, but there is no reason for OP to include stdio.h when iostream is sufficient.

Comment: thand for the advice above! The problem is not about stdio.h . Why I include stdio.h ? That's my coding habbits... using printf and scanf would be more efficient for file operations, but using cout and cin would be more convenient for most cases(I thought).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why would this happen?

You wanted to step into `void hello()` but stepped into `std::string` copy constructor. Now you can go out of `std::string` constructor using `finish` command and step into `void hello()`:

```
(gdb) finish
(gdb) step
```

Another option is to pass string argument to `void hello()` by reference to avoid unnecessary copying. That way you will step into desired function with only a single step:

```
void hello(const string& str) {
    cout << str << endl;
}
```

Comment: thx. Both two way can help to step into the function! But for the first option , it seems to step into the assembly code.

Comment: That's because you have not installed debug info for gcc/libstdc++. But if your goal is to step into `hello()` you can ignore this.

Comment: Thanks~ really helpful